# what is the difference between ETSI-M2M standard and OneM2M standard?

Tags: iot, m2m, onem2m

I am doing a project about the topic desinging and implementing an M2M Application using OM2M. When I found some documentation in the internet, I know that the OM2M is defined based on the ETSI-M2M and OneM2M Standard. These two standards make me a bit confused about the similarity. Can anyone tell me what is the difference between these two standards, the ETSI-M2M standard and OneM2M standard?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will try to help from the standard prospective, not in terms of the implementation
ETSI M2M was developed starting form 2009, and two releases were completed.  In the meantime was identified the need to globalize the solution, so ETSI and its members approched other companies and other Standard Organizations to build a common project, and this is today oneM2M.

It is worth to remember that oneM2M is not a new Standard Organization, it is simply shared Partnership Project among existing organizations to merge the efforts and the expertize to provide better specifications.

Technically speaking, the principles are the same, the key Resources are still Applications, Containers and Access Rights (ACP in oneM2M). And the principle of separation of the semantic treatment from the platform is still the same.
So de facto Release 1 of oneM2M is a sort of "Release 3" of ETSI M2M. But be careful, they are not backward compatible.

Being practical, I would suggest you to look directly at Release 1 and 2 of oneM2M. A lot of improvement has been added by the different partners making it more easily usable.
In particular Release 2 finalizes the semantic interworking framework to be build around the platform, providing inter technology interworking and data sharing.

I hope I was usefull.

Enrico Scarrone,
Telecom Italia - TIM

ETSI SmartM2M Chairman,
oneM2M Steering Comittee Vice Chair

Comment: Hi Enrico, thank you for your useful explanation. As I understand so far that the OneM2M is some kind of the improvement of the ETSI M2M standard. Just that simple and that's it, isn't it? And one more thing that I am quite confused is that the interfaces in the OneM2M and ETSI M2M are difference, in ETSI we have mIa, mId, dIa; and in OneM2M we have mca, mcn, mcc. Are they equally or not?